# how to display if some website is working or not in html

Tags: html

I need some sort of script that would announce if some website (the links wouldn't be part of my website) is reachable (online) or not. It would look like this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>website 1</td>
    <td>working/not working</td>       
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>website 2</td>
    <td>working/not working</td>       
  </tr>
</table>
```

Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/

Comment: Will try that (hopefully I make it work, I'm still pretty much a begginer). Many thanks!